# XSLT code for generating HTML rows, of two, from a series of XML child nodes

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am very new to XSLT.  I am stuck at a point in my project.  I need to take the XML below and produce the desired HTML below.

I need to take the child nodes under the subsection 'additional' and group them two-by-two into HTML  rows with a left and a right element in each row.

I can manage to get the proper left right elements.  Then I can either group all the child nodes into one big row or each child into an individual row.  However, I am unable to produce HTML groups of two within a row with a left and right element.

I need to limit the number of additional stories to the show="" attribute.  This will always return an even integer.  I have the limiting working and I can calculate the number of rows.  But cannot break them into rows of two.

I know you need to use the copy node but I cannot make it work.

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<fullpage>
<section name="tops">
    <subsect name="featured" count="1">
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align></align>
            <size>2</size>
        </article>
    </subsect>
    <subsect name="additional" count="7" show="6">
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>right</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>right</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>right</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
    </subsect>
</section>
<section name="section2">
    <article>
        ...
    </article>
    <article>
        ...
    </article>
    <article>
        ...
    </article>
    <article>
        ...
    </article>
</section>
</fullpage>
```

Here is the XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>

<xsl:variable name="topadd" select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='additional']/@show" />
<xsl:variable name="topaddrows" select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='additional']/@show div 2" />

<!-- top news -->
<div class="bucket">
    <xsl:for-each select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='featured']">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="article/size = '2'">
         <div class="col2Feature">
            <ul>
             <li> Two <xsl:value-of select="article/title"/> </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="article/size = '4'">
         <div class="col4Feature">
            <ul>
             <li> Four <xsl:value-of select="article/title"/> </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="article/size = '6'">
         <div class="col6Feature">
            <ul>
             <li> Six <xsl:value-of select="article/title"/> </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="article/size = '8'">
         <div class="col8Feature">
            <ul>
             <li> Eight <xsl:value-of select="article/title"/> </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
        </xsl:when>
     </xsl:choose>
     <!-- /feature -->

    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
<!-- /top news --> 

<xsl:value-of select="$topaddrows"/>
<xsl:for-each select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='additional']/article">
 <xsl:if test="not(position() > $topadd)">
    <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="align = 'left'">
        <div class="bucketL">
         <ul>
            <li> <xsl:value-of select="title"/> </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="align = 'right'">
        <div class="bucketR">
         <ul>
            <li> <xsl:value-of select="title"/> </li>
         </ul>
        </div>
     </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bucket">
<div class="col2Feature">
    <ul>
        <li> Two Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<div class="bucketL">
    <ul>
        <li>Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="bucketR">
    <ul>
        <li>Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<div class="bucketL">
    <ul>
        <li>Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="bucketR">
    <ul>
        <li>Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col2">
<div class="bucketL">
    <ul>
        <li>Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="bucketR">
    <ul>
        <li>Title Element</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do what you want to achieve, is to change the current **xsl:for-each** to only pick the **article** elements that appear first in each 'row'. i.e. the **article** elements in postion 1, 3, 5, etc...

```
<xsl:for-each select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='additional']
                      /article[position() mod 2 = 1]">
```

In fact, you could add your check on the total number of **article** elements to the condition too, to avoid having the **xsl:if** check.

```
<xsl:for-each select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='additional']
                      /article[not(position() > $topadd)][position() mod 2 = 1]">
```

Then, within this XSLT loop, you can output the title for the current article, and the following article, like so

```
<div class="col2">
    <div class="bucketL">
     <ul>
        <li> <xsl:value-of select="title"/> </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bucketR">
     <ul>
        <li> <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::article[1]/title"/> </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are keen to learn XSLT though, it is worth pointing out your XSLT can be tided up a bit, as there is a lot of repeated code.

For example, you use the xpath expression `fullpage/section[@name='tops']` in a number of places. You can simplify this by making use of template matching, which is where XSLT comes into is own. You would start off by selecting the top section like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']"/>
```

Then, within the template that matches **section** to get the **articles** you would do this, which this, which is slightly shorter than the current **xsl:for-each**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="subsect[@name='additional']/article[not(position() &gt; $topadd)][position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
```

You can also make use of Attribute Value Templates as well. For example, to output the **class** attribute for your 'featured' section, you can just do this

```
<div class="col{article/size}Feature">
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally.

Try this XSLT. When applied to you XML, it should hopefully give the output your need.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:variable name="topadd" select="/fullpage/section[@name='tops']/subsect[@name='additional']/@show"/>
   <xsl:variable name="topaddrows" select="$topadd div 2"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <div class="bucket">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="fullpage/section[@name='tops']"/>
            </div>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="section">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="subsect[@name='featured']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="subsect[@name='additional']/article[not(position() &gt; $topadd)][position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="subsect">
      <div class="col{article/size}Feature">
         <ul>
            <li>
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="article/size = '2'"> Two </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="article/size = '4'"> Four </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="article/size = '6'"> Six </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:when test="article/size = '8'"> Eight </xsl:when>
               </xsl:choose>
               <xsl:value-of select="article/title"/>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="article">
      <div class="col2">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::article[1]/title">
            <xsl:with-param name="class" select="'bucketR'"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="title">
      <xsl:param name="class" select="'bucketL'"/>
      <div class="{$class}">
         <ul>
            <li>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note the use of parameters in the final template, so that a different class name can be output for the left and right titles.

Comment: Both your code and Ken's code worked perfectly in my project.  I voted your answer the best because you broke down and explained the code line-by-line.  You also provided great educational notes for example what curly brackets mean in XSLT. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below is a solution that simply calculates the rows based on the size, without any presumption built into the stylesheet.  I had to guess where you were getting some of your class names from, but I figured you could modify that.  This uses XSLT 2.0 ... if you are stuck with XSLT 1.0 then you can follow up with Tim's solution.  The solution below illustrates what I teach my students about grouping by a calculation rather than grouping by content (many students believe you have to do grouping by content).

```
t:\ftemp>type joe.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<fullpage>
<section name="tops">
    <subsect name="featured" count="1">
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align></align>
            <size>2</size>
        </article>
    </subsect>
    <subsect name="additional" count="7" show="6">
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>right</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>right</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>right</align>
        </article>
        <article>
            <url>http://www.myurl.com</url>
            <title>Title Element</title>
            <description>Description</description>
            <align>left</align>
        </article>
    </subsect>
</section>
</fullpage>
t:\ftemp>call xslt2 joe.xml joe.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="bucket">
         <div class="col2Feature">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
         <div class="bucketL">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="bucketR">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
         <div class="bucketL">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="bucketR">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
         <div class="bucketL">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="bucketR">
            <ul>
               <li>Title Element</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
t:\ftemp>type joe.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes" 
            doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="fullpage/section"/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
  <xsl:variable name="cols" select="subsect[1]/article/size"/>
  <div class="bucket">
    <div class="col{$cols}Feature">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="subsect[1]/article/title/node()"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <xsl:for-each-group group-by="(position()-1) idiv $cols"
    select="subsect[2]/article[position()&lt;=current()/subsect[2]/@show]">
    <div class="col{$cols}">
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <div class="bucket{upper-case(substring(align,1,1))}">
          <ul>
            <li><xsl:apply-templates select="title/node()"/></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Thank you Ken!  Your answer did work.  I only checked Tim's answer because of the extra pointers he provided in his answer.  I did learn from your code as well and thank you!